# How to use `NULL` in a `where` clause

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite3 I am combining entries from various tables in a new table (making use ot primary and foreign key contsraints; for details see at the bottom):

```
select * from files;
id          file            description       
----------  --------------  ----------------  
1           testmodel1.dat  first test model
2           testmodel2.dat  second test mode

select * from patches;
id          patch        description
----------  ----------  ------------
1           testpatch   test patch
```

Combined table:

```
select * from patched_files;
id          files_id    patches_id
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           NULL
2           1           1
3           2           1
```

Some files do get patched some not (sometimes the same file).

I would like to retrieve this view from the database (expected result):

```
id          file            patch
----------  --------------  ----------
1           testmodel1.dat  
2           testmodel1.dat  testpatch
3           testmodel2.dat  testpatch
```

I tried this:

```
select patched_files.id as id,patched_files.files_id as file_id, files.file as file, patched_files.patches_id as patch_id, patches.patch as patch 
from patched_files, files, patches 
where patched_files.files_id=files.id and patched_files.patches_id=patches.id;

id          files_id    file            patches_id  patch
----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
2           1           testmodel1.dat  1           testpatch
3           2           testmodel2.dat  1           testpatch
```

Here, I am missing the unpatched file (rowid 1) and I understand why. 
So I added an `or`:

```
select patched_files.id as id,patched_files.files_id as file_id, files.file as file, patched_files.patches_id as patch_id, patches.patch as patch 
from patched_files, files, patches 
where patched_files.files_id=files.id and (patched_files.patches_id=patches.id or patched_files.patches_id is NULL);

id          file_id     file            patch_id    patch
----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
1           1           testmodel1.dat  NULL        testpatch
2           1           testmodel1.dat  1           testpatch
3           2           testmodel2.dat  1           testpatch
```

I understand why this is happening (composite table from "files" and "patches").

How can I avoid the patch name being stated if the patch_id is NULL?
Do I need to insert a "dummy" in the "patches" table?

Recreating the example:

```
-- original files:
create table files (id integer primary key, file text, description text);
insert into  files (file, description) values('testmodel1.dat', 'first test model');
insert into  files (file, description) values('testmodel2.dat', 'second test model');
-- patches:
create table patches (id integer primary key, patch text, description text);
insert into  patches (patch, description) values('testpatch', 'test patch');
-- patched files (combination of files and patches):
create table patched_files (id integer primary key, files_id integer references files(id) on delete restrict deferrable initially deferred, patches_id integer references patches(id) on delete restrict deferrable initially deferred);
insert into  patched_files (files_id) values(1);
insert into  patched_files (files_id, patches_id) values(1,1);
insert into  patched_files (files_id, patches_id) values(2,1);
```

Comment: You need to switch to the explicit join syntax and don't use the old legacy style any more. Use a `left join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an outer join:

```
select f.id, f.file, p.patch, p.description
from files f 
  left join patched_files pf on pf.files_id = f.id
  left join patches p on p.id = pf.patches_id
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZNMAY53081

Comment: Thanks for pointing into the right direction. Answer excepted. My final query: `
select pf.id, f.file, p.patch from patched_files pf left outer join files f on pf.files_id = f.id left outer join patches p on p.id = pf.patches_id;`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the privileges yet to correct my own comment... I obviously mean **accepted** and `select pf.id, f.file, p.patch from patched_files pf left outer join files f on pf.files_id = f.id left outer join patches p on p.id = pf.patches_id;`